# Is it possible to add style (cell background color) to a excel exported file using kendo-grid-excel?

Tags: angular, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, export-to-excel

I need some help with an example you could give me.
I want to know how to add style (cell background color) to a excel exported file using kendo-grid-exce

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The example [here](https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/grid/export/excel-export/#toc-customizing-generated-workbooks) does exactly that:

```
public onExcelExport(e: any): void {
    const rows = e.workbook.sheets[0].rows;

    // align multi header
    rows[0].cells[2].hAlign = 'center';

    // set alternating row color
    let altIdx = 0;
    rows.forEach((row) => {
        if (row.type === 'data') {
            if (altIdx % 2 !== 0) {
                row.cells.forEach((cell) => {
                    cell.background = '#aabbcc';
                });
            }
            altIdx++;
        }
    });
}
```